# Curl IPv6 /48 Addresses PHP --interface

Tags: php, linux, networking, curl, ipv6

I have the following function(in functions.php, for example purposes..):

```
function url_get_contents($url, $ip){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

I need to have this function mount to IPv6 addresses that are in a mounted /48 on my interface (sit1).

The following is my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-sit1:

```
DEVICE=sit1
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6TUNNELIPV4=**.***.**.***
IPV6TUNNELIPV4LOCAL=***.**.**.**
IPV6ADDR=****:***:*:***::*/64
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="****:***:*:***::/48"
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=****:***:*:***::*
```

Obviously in the above code, IP addresses have been starred out.

However, in php:

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');
function randomString(){
$length = 16;
$chars = "0123456789abcdef";
$str = "";    
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){ $str .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)]; }
$str = str_split($str, 4); $str = implode(":", $str);
return $str;
}
$url="http://www.whatismyipv6.com";
$ip="****:***:*:***::" . randomString();
$res=url_get_contents($url, $ip);
print($res);
exit();
?>
```

This doesn't seem to work (address cannot be bound to possibly??).

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

** NOTE: THIS ALL WORKS IF I MANUALLY ADD THE IP WITH /128 IN ifcfg-sit1**

Comment: Why are you bothering to bind to a specific IP address?

Comment: So that I can go out on a different IP each time, which is generated from the /48. I will add that function to above.

Comment: OK...I am sure I've seen something about this before, but I can't find it right now. I'll try to come back to it later.

Comment: K. I read a few other threads here where noone seems to know how to do it,however, I don't take "no way to do it" as an answer, seeing as there is always a way even if you have to do a lot of work to get it done. I've never found anything that couldn't be work-around'd to get it done.

Comment: Hi @GH_EBER are you find are solution for this?